# Disappearing tkinter images when label is placed

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter, label

I am currently making a GUI application using Python an TkInter and I have problem with images "randomly" disappearing. I am aware that you need to keep references to your images to prevent them from being garbage collected, and I don't believe this is what causes my problems.

What I currently have are TkInter labels with images on them. The issues arise when I either move my window between screens (I have two monitors) or sometimes when I add new labels to the canvas. What happens is that a select few (not all) images disappear, but they will reappear if I re-size my window. What I have tried is to issue a redraw by calling the update() method on the root tk element but this does not solve my issues. Is this a known issue in TkInter?

Edit:

Here is the specific piece of code that makes the images disappear:

```
def showNoMatch():
    global tkImageNoMatch, noMatchLabel, panel
    img = Image.open("noMatches.png")
    tkImageNoMatch = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    noMatchLabel = Label(panel, image = tkImageNoMatch, borderwidth = 0)
    noMatchLabel.place(x = 250, y = 550)
```

Which has the following effects on my gui:

Before adding the noMatchLabel:
[image: Before adding the noMatchLabel]

And after adding the noMatchLabel:
[image: After adding the noMatchLabel]

Notice that the two buttons on the sides disappear, yet they reappear when I re-size the window.

Comment: This isn't exactly a coding question, with it not including code, but asking for information about if there is any known issues with code. This could have easily been researched on it's own, and if not, include your code within the question.

Comment: I've added the specific code that causes the issues. I disagree that this is easily researched. It is probably for you, but you also most certainly have more experience in this field than me.

Comment: Alright then, I will take the time to look at it. I trust you on the research aspect, a flaw like that would be obvious in tkinter, so hang fire for a moment. Hrm, how did you place the buttons on the side, in many cases they are displaced depending on the situation. Your best bet would be to stick the bars at the bottom and the buttons on the side in a frame together and then place it, so it stays together in one place.

Comment: I don't think the buttons are displaced since clicking on the location of the buttons triggers the events I've set up to happen.

Comment: This might be out of my expertise, would you mind giving me the file?

Comment: It seem obvious that the no match label covers up the buttons.  Move the buttons  up so it won't  obscure them.